# how do i open Hands.py file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, mediapipe

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands()
```

i want to access the parameters of "Hands" in vscode
i know you can do it in pycharm by just hold on ctrl while perssing "Hands"

Answer (score 0):

1-You have to use the debugging tool, if you don't have to go to the Extension tab or press `CTRL+Shift+X` and install python

2-you can set breakpoint and start debugging you only can debug and see your source code to See Hands.py source code `From Extension Tab Go to Configuration Then Select` Add Configuration`And select Python and  modify` *JustMyCode*   to Be  `False`
[image]

[image]